# How to remove class with media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When **@media screen and (max-width: 500px)** is in active removing class ***.fade*** . How can i do this? my script is here below.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .post_profile_image{
        width:35px;
        height:35px
    }
    .fade{
    /* Remove this class */
    }
}

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

Comment: You can't add or remove classes usin css.

Comment: can i remove class with **javascript** When @media screen and (max-width: 500px) is in active .?? or other solutions??

Comment: you can either use jquery or javascript for the same.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How to remove class with media queries

You don't. Instead, you define new rules that apply to the class which do the styling you want done. Media queries can't add or remove classes to elements, they merely change what rules apply to elements.

Comment: `.fade {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
}`

Comment: how to disable animation when When @media screen and (max-width: 500px) is in active .fade

Comment: @ÄRÂmmãřŻąîñh: That's a **different** question (and one I don't happen to know the answer to).

Comment: can i remove class with **javascript** when When @media screen and (max-width: 500px) is in active .?? or other sollutions??

Comment: @ÄRÂmmãřŻąîñh: Just post a question asking how to stop the transition with a subsequent media query. Someone will know the answer. You *can* remove the class by using something like `matchMedia`, but the better answer would be to just use CSS.

Answer (score 10):

```
$(window).resize(function(){
 If($(window).width()<500){
  $('.fade').removeClass('fade');
 }
});
```

Comment: Thire some error . i dont know why is not working !!

Comment: -1: I recommend against this as it won't consider scrollbar width inconsistencies across different browser. Instead use `window.matchMedia`.

Comment: you can use window.innerWidth

Answer (score 2):

With CSS only you can't remove it from the DOM.. But.. You can overwrite it. Simply define that class in the right place.

Resize the HTML box in jsFiddle.

DEMO: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michmammo93/te1fagkL/)

HTML

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

CSS:

```
.fade { 
     opacity: 0; 
     transition: opacity 0.15s linear;
     -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear; 
     -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear; 
}

.fade:hover {
    opacity: 1
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 500px) {
    .post_profile_image{
        width:35px;
        height:35px
    }
    .fade{
        transition: none;
        -o-transition: none; 
        -webkit-transition: none; 
    }

}
```

Comment: `.fade { opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear; -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear; transition: opacity 0.15s linear; }` i want remove transition when media query is active??

Answer (score 1):

Check this code. I Hope, it helps you.

```js
   $(window).on('resize', function(){
              var win = $(this); //this = window
              if (win.width()< 500) { $('#myModal').removeClass('fade'); }
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">Hello there</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more easily,check this

```js
if($(".toChange").css("border-block-color") == "rgb(0, 0 , 0)"){

$(".toChange").removeClass("toQuit")

}

//Basic, if the ".toChange" element has a property in css that is equal to "rgb(0, 0, 0)" that is the way to refer to black color. We proceed to execute the next block.

// In the next Block we use .removeClass("name_of_class_what_we_wanna_destroy") to quit the "toQuit" class when this happen
```

```css
@media (min-width: 1900px){
.toChange{
  border-block-color:aliceblue!important;
  }
}

/* we use media screen to send a style that the browser won't show, but the jquery can read, so this is easier way, don't you worry, the property border-block-color is almost invisible, it's only used to make one change when the window's size be = than what when are looking for to quit the class

- less Css 
- less JQuery 
+ More production

*/
```

```html
<div class="toChange toQuit">
</div>
<!-- We wanna quit the "toQuit" class when window size is > than 1900px -->
```

hope help anyone :D

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function(){
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        if(window.innerWidth < 500){
            $('#slide-menu').removeClass('fade');
            
        }
    });
});
```